# Making generic function async fails on type conversion due to using Task<T>

Tags: c#, type-inference

Here is the structure of given interfaces and classes:

```
public abstract class Entity
{ }

public class Group : Entity
{ }

public interface ICollectionPage<T>
{ }

public interface IGraphServiceGroupsCollectionPage : ICollectionPage<Group>
{ }
```

And here are two methods, that use these interfaces. One is sync and the other is async, thous using `Task<T>` for the arguments:

```
private static Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAllAsync<T>(Task<ICollectionPage<T>> collectionTask)
    where T : Entity
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

private static Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAll<T>(ICollectionPage<T> collectionTask)
    where T : Entity
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

If we try to use the synchronous method within our code, everything works as expected:

```
var collectionPage = (IGraphServiceGroupsCollectionPage)null;
var groups = GetAll(collectionPage);
```

But if we try to use the async method, we got a type conversion error:

```
var collectionPageTask = (Task<IGraphServiceGroupsCollectionPage>)null;
var groupsFromAsync = GetAllAsync<IGraphServiceGroupsCollectionPage>(collectionPageTask);
```

> error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<RemotePowershell.IGraphServiceGroupsCollectionPage>' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<RemotePowershell.ICollectionPage<RemotePowershell.IGraphServiceGroupsCollectionPage>>'

Any idea on how we can avoid this error in the async call?

The complete code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public interface IGraphServiceClient
{
}

public abstract class Entity
{
}

public class Group : Entity
{
}

public interface ICollectionPage<T>
{
}

public interface IGraphServiceGroupsCollectionPage : ICollectionPage<Group>
{
}

public class Program
{
    private static Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAllAsync<T>(Task<ICollectionPage<T>> collectionTask)
        where T : Entity
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private static Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAll<T>(ICollectionPage<T> collectionTask)
        where T : Entity
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var collectionPage = (IGraphServiceGroupsCollectionPage)null;
        var groups = GetAll(collectionPage);
        var collectionPageTask = (Task<IGraphServiceGroupsCollectionPage>)null;
        var groupsFromAsync = GetAllAsync<IGraphServiceGroupsCollectionPage>(collectionPageTask);
    }
}
```

### Update due to: Why do you want to do this?

The reason is quite simple. In the first step, we'd like to write an extension method to another async method. This method has the following signature:

```
public interface IGraphServiceUsersCollectionRequest
{
    public Task<IGraphServiceGroupsCollectionPage> GetAsync();
}
```

And when we like to call it we like to do it this way:

```
var request = (IGraphServiceUsersCollectionRequest)null;
var result = await request.GetAsync().GetAllAsync();
```

And to get this to work, we need an extension method that takes an `Task<IGraphServiceGroupsCollectionPage>` as input and returns an `Task<IEnumerable<Group>>`. By trying to build this extension method we ran into the above problems and we boild it down to the above given example.

Comment: The return types are different, this has little to do with async and Task. The error complains about converting `IGraphServiceGroupsCollectionPage` to `ICollectionPage<IGraphServiceGroupsCollectionPage>`

Comment: Why does `GetAllAsync` accept a `Task<ICollectionPage<T>> collectionTask` instead of `ICollectionPage<T>` ? Why not `await` any previous tasks and pass the result to the method? Even if you used `.ContinueWith` you'd pass the result to any subsequent method

Comment: Yeah you wont be able to force your parameters into `Task<T> like that

Comment: `GetAllAsync` accepts a `Task<>` cause we'd like to use this as extension method on the real code and in that case we would get a fluent syntax writing.

Comment: There's no difference with async calls. The `async` keyword doesn't affect anything, it's just a marker telling the compiler the method can use `await`.  Passing a task as a parameter to another method is extremely rare though. Why are you doing this?

Comment: forget async, this is a typing issue not a TPL issue

Comment: So the real question is how to get fluent syntax *and* inheritance to work with generics. There's no inheritance relation here though, just as there's no inheritance relation between `List<Child>` and `List<Parent>`. This is about [covariance and contravariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/)

Comment: There is an inheritance relation, cause `IGraphServiceGroupsCollectionPage` implements `ICollectionPage<Group>`

Comment: But `Task` isn't an interface so there's no variance relation. Just as `List<Child>` and `List<Parent>` have no inheritance relation, `Task<Child>` and `Task<Parent>` have no inheritance relation

Comment: Check [Variance in Generic interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/variance-in-generic-interfaces) to see why passing the interfaces as one another works.

Comment: Wait: `IGraphServiceGroupsCollectionPage` **doesn't inherit from** `ICollectionPage<IGraphServiceGroupsCollectionPage>`, it implements `ICollectionPage<Group>`. That's what the error complains about.

Comment: So the error is probably a typo. Which leaves the real question - how to chain asynchronous operations. `await request.GetAsync().GetAll()` is invalid unless you have a `GetAll()` overload that accepts `Task<T>` and returns tasks too. `await` applies to the result of the entire chain, not just the first call

Comment: No, it is not a typo. `IGraphServiceGroupsCollectionPage` implements `ICollectionPage<Group>` and the method works on `Task<ICollectionPage<T>>`. So IMHO it should compile.

Comment: Even though the two interfaces are unrelated? We aren't talking about `ICollectionPage<Group>`, we're talking about `ICollectionPage<IGraphServiceGroupsCollectionPage>`. Why should it ever compile? Are you able to assign `ICollectionPage<IGraphServiceGroupsCollectionPage>` to an `IGraphServiceGroupsCollectionPage` or vice versa?

Comment: But nowhere in my code is a `ICollectionPage<IGraphServiceGroupsCollectionPage>`. There is only an `IGraphServiceGroupsCollectionPage` and this implements `ICollectionPage<Groups>`.

Comment: "But nowhere in my code is a `ICollectionPage<IGraphServiceGroupsCollectionPage>`" - well, there is, effectively - the parameter type of a call to `GetAllAsync<IGraphServiceGroupsCollectionPage>` is `Task<ICollectionPage<IGraphServiceGroupsCollectionPage>>` after type parameter substitution.

Comment: @JonSkeet: As usual, you're right. This was a typo be me and not my intended code. So sorry, that it took so long, to see this in my code.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to make the `Task` parameter  more generic.

```
private static Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAllAsync<T,T2>(Task<T> collectionTask)
   where T : ICollectionPage<T2>
   where T2 : Entity
{
   throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

...

```
var collectionPageTask = (Task<IGraphServiceGroupsCollectionPage>)null;
var groupsFromAsync = GetAllAsync<IGraphServiceGroupsCollectionPage,Entity>(collectionPageTask);
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the "here's what to do" - my answer provides the "this is why it doesn't compile at the moment".

Comment: @JonSkeet alley oop, slamdunk

Comment: Yes, this works, but now type inference is gone. So if you try to call this method without explicitly specifing the generic arguments it fails.

Comment: @Oliver this is indeed the problem, see jons explanation why this cant be done otherwise

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `Task<T>` (being a class) is invariant. From the comments in the question:

> `IGraphServiceGroupsCollectionPage` implements `ICollectionPage<Group>` and the method works on `Task<ICollectionPage<T>>`.

You're expecting a `Task<IGraphServiceGroupsCollectionPage>` to be compatible with `Task<ICollectionPage<Group>>`. It isn't. You can tell that very simply:

```cs
Task<IGraphServiceGroupsCollectionPage> task1 = null;
Task<ICollectionPage<Group>> task2 = task1;
```

This gives an error of:

> Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<IGraphServiceGroupsCollectionPage>' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ICollectionPage<Group>>'

Additionally, this call:

```cs
GetAllAsync<IGraphServiceGroupsCollectionPage>(collectionPageTask)
```

... is providing an explicit type argument of `IGraphServiceGroupsCollectionPage` for `T`, and the parameter is of type `ICollectionPage<T>`, so the compiler is trying to convert the argument to an `Task<ICollectionPage<IGraphServiceGroupsCollectionPage>>`.

[Michael Randall has shown the solution to this, making the call generic in two type parameters instead of one.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63738109/22656).